# Chaquopy Android Wrapper

Tags: python, android, pandas

**Chaquopy Android** I have to call the python file method with array data. then python file executes ECG Peak(PQRST) using **neurokit2** and got this error.

[image]

code is properly work in pycharm. there is no TypeError
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas added support for the `string` dtype in [version 1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#dedicated-string-data-type). So change the `pip` section of your build.gradle file to install `pandas==1.3.2`, which we released for Chaquopy a few days ago.