# Chaquopy 11.0 Python.start() time application is crash

Tags: android, chaquopy

I am using Chaquopy 11.0 lib for the existing project but I have start
**Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(parent.getApplicationContext()));**
application is crash. Please help.

[image]

Comment: I see from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996540) that you already know how to get the [stack trace from the Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174). So please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Hello, this is a different error regarding pandas version error but I have started Python app is crash. @PeterSmith

Comment: If that red error is the cause of your crash, it probably has nothing to do with Chaquopy. Try searching for the text on StackOverflow or Google.